# set environment variable command messes up terminal

Tags: bash, grep, awk

I have a command to get the docker root directory as follows:

```
$ docker info | grep "Docker Root Dir: " | awk '{print $NF}'

/mnt/blah/docker-data
```

Which works fine.  But, when I attempt to set an environment variable using this command the terminal won't accept any more commands and gives out a weird error:

```
$ DOCKER_ROOT_DIR=$(docker info | grep "Docker Root Dir: " | awk '{print $NF}')

    ~ $ DOCKER_ROOT_DIR=$(docker info | grep "Docker Root Dir: " | awk '{print $NF}')
    docker:~: command not found
    ~ $ : command not found
    ~ $ : command not found
    ~ $
```

I can't type any commands and ENTER or ^C results in `: command not found`.

What silly thing have I done wrong?

Answer:

```
~ $ trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
trap -- 'trap_handler $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
~ $ echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$ \[\e]2;echo:~\a\]
~ $ echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"

~ $
~ $ declare -f trap_handler
trap_handler () 
{ 
    LAST_CMD=`echo "$1"`;
    NICE_PWD=`pwd | sed 's/\/home\/rowead/~/'`;
    set-title $LAST_CMD:$NICE_PWD
}
```

```

```
 # function to set terminal title

 function set-title(){
   if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
     ORIG=$PS1
   fi
   TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
   if [ -n "${VIRTUAL_ENV}" ]; then
     venv=`basename "${VIRTUAL_ENV}"`
     PS1=($venv)${ORIG}${TITLE}
   else
     PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
   fi
 }
```

Comment: In a new terminal, check the following: 1. `trap` 2 `echo "$PS1"` 3. `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"`

Comment: OK, and now `declare -f trap_handler` as well, please.

Comment: Down the rabbit hole, with `set-title`, now and if that uses any functions, those too, please.